# compare the two strings and take the difference between them in percent (php)

Tags: php, string, compare

Help please to compare two strings and take the difference between them in percent

I had two strings like:

```
first string:
253.0.0.0,253.0.0.0,253.0.0.0,253.0.0.0,253.0.0.0,253.0.0.0,253.0.0.0,253.0.0.0,253.0.0.0,253.0.0.0,253.0.0.0,253.0.0.0,247.0.0.24,197.0.0.35,189.0.0.98....
second string:
255.255.255.127,255.255.255.127,255.255.255.127,255.255.255.127,255.255.255.127,255.255.255.127,255.255.255.127,255.255.255.127,255.255.255.127....

$first_array = explode(",", $out_string);
$second_array = explode(",", $out_string_1);
$result_array = array_merge(array_diff($first_array, $second_array), array_diff($second_array, $first_array));

$result = implode(",",$result_array);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two interesting native functions for this purpose, [similar_text()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.similar-text.php) and [levenshtein()](https://www.php.net/levenshtein)

Example of similar_text():

```
$string1 = 'AAAb';
$string2 = 'aaab';

similar_text ( $string1, $string2, $percentege );

echo $percentege . '%'; // Output: 25%
```

Example of levenshtein():

```
levenshtein($string1, $string2, 1, 1000, 1000000);
```

**EDIT 1**

Considering that the first string always have the same quantity of entries that second string, you can try the below code. I've created two strings for test purpose, second string has two equal entries and 7 different entries in a total of 9.

```
$first_string = '253.0.0.1,253.0.0.2,253.0.0.3,253.0.0.4,253.0.0.5,253.0.0.6,253.0.0.7,253.0.0.8,253.0.0.9';

$second_string = '253.0.0.1,253.0.0.2,255.255.255.127,255.255.255.128,255.255.255.129,255.255.255.130,255.255.255.131,255.255.255.132,255.255.255.133';

$first_array = explode(',', $first_string);

$second_array = explode(',', $second_string);

$total_entries = count($first_array);

$array_differences = array_diff($first_array, $second_array);

$different_entries = count($array_differences);

$percentage = ( $different_entries / $total_entries ) * 100 ;

echo 'Difference: ' . round($percentage, 2) . '%';
```

Comment: I admit I thought about them too. ) But considered them not relevant for this specific task, as it's basically about comparing the arrays (of IP addresses, obviously), and not pure strings.

Comment: @raina77ow, Does the strings have the same quantity of IP addresses?

Comment: its not ip addresses it's a RGBA CODE and they have same quantity

Comment: @VolodyaDaniliv, Please see if my EDIT 1 helps you

Answer (score 1):

How about as simple as...

```
$difference = count($result_array) / count($first_array) * 100;
```

For example:

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$arr2 = array(5, 2, 4, 8);
$res  = array_diff($arr1, $arr2); 
printf("%.02f%%", count($res) / count($arr1) * 100);    # 50.00%
```

Comment: You might interpret "difference" as "percentage change" too, in which case the numerator term would be `count($first_array) - count($result_array)`.

Comment: Sure, I assumed it was about the share.

Comment: @VolodyaDaniliv And what's expected if they are different? 0%?

Comment: I need to know how much the first array differs from the second in percentage

Comment: @VolodyaDaniliv If they're completely different, what's expected - other than 100%, I mean?

Comment: the problem is that the two array are not completely different, only a few elements

Comment: Can you show a (shortened) example of arrays that give an incorrect result here?

Answer (score 1):

The similarity function depends strongly on the context in which will be implemented. Without an explanation of what you want to do with the result of the comparison (i.e. your context) it's almost impossible to give you a similarity function out of the box. Although all of the similarity functions I can think of could be valid, none of them could be suited for your problem.